# $(...).offest is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am baffled to why I am experiencing this error, maybe its a bug with Jquery or maybe I'm blind, but Jquery has loaded and I can access the offset function after selecting an element?

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offest is not a function

According to w3, I've used the function [correctly.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp)

**Current code**

```
var off = $("#canvas").offest();
var xPos = off.left + ( jqo.outerWidth(true)/2 );
var yPos = off.top + ( jqo.outerHeight(true)/2 );
console.log(yPos, xPos);
```

Comment: You've spelt `offset()` incorrectly...

Comment: You have written "offest", where as should be "offset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo. Use `offset` instead of `offest`:

```
var off = $("#canvas").offset();
```